# LateInitializationError: Field 'screenWidth' has not been initialized. Exception in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, exception

I am new to flutter
I had this size config file and I used it in an old project
and right now I took it again to another project and it shows no errors but when I run it gives me an Exception :
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown building Body(dirty):
LateInitializationError: Field 'screenWidth' has not been initialized.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SizeConfig {
  static late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static late double screenWidth;
  static late double screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;
  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}
// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}
// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  // 375 is the layout width that designer use
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

Comment: Failed to initialization that's why you got the error. When you declare with the `late` keyword, you need to initialize as well, I think `void init(BuildContext context)` does not call perfectly outside where you used `screenWidth`.

Answer (score 6):

make sure you call the method init() in build method

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SizeConfig().init(context);}
```

and make sure you import sizeconfig class from the right source
for example :

import 'package:to_app/ui/size_config.dart';

where you want to use it

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure `ScreenConfig.init()` is called before you use `ScreenConfig.screenWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use a Sizer package if that, then wrap your material in Sizer like :

//
return Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
return const MaterialApp(
home: Home(),
);
});